# How to sort two sorted arrays without using sort methods (sort) nor sort algorithms (bubble sort, quick sort)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, big-o

I was asked in an interview and my answer was similar to this, which is wrong due to the final loop.

```js
const newSortArrays = (arr1, arr2) => {
     let output = [];
     while (arr1.length && arr2.length) {
        if (arr1[0] < arr2[0]) 
         output.push(arr1[0] < arr2[0] ? arr1.shift() : arr2.shift())
     }
     return [...output, ...arr1, ...arr2]
 }
```

Comment: You should just `return output`;

Comment: After the loop ends, `arr1` and `arr2` are empty, there's no need to merge them into the result.

Comment: Not if the array lengths are not equal @Barmar.

Comment: Oh right. I was thinking the loop condition was `||`, not `&&`.

Comment: But the if is superfluous/wrong. Remove that and it seems correct?(Without testing it).

Comment: But what is your question ?

Comment: @Barmar: with an `||` condition, the code crashes. See why ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Because it tries to access the element of an empty an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are talking about — "sorting" two arrays that are each themselves already sorted — is called a ***merge***. This is how you do that:

```js
function merge( left = [] , right = [] )  {
  const merged = new Array( left.length + right.length );

  let i = 0 ;
  let j = 0 ;
  let k = 0 ;

  // while both lists have items
  while ( i < left.length && j < right.length ) {
    const x = left[i];
    const y = right[j];

    if ( x <= y ) {
      merged[k++] = x;
      ++i;
    } else {
      merged[k++] = y;
      ++j;
    }

  }

  // if the left list still has items, take them
  while ( i < left.length ) {
    merged[k++] = left[ i++ ];
  }

  // if the right list still has items, take them
  while ( j < right.length ) {
    merged[k++] = right[ j++ ];
  }

  return merged;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A (less efficient) single-loop variant:

```
  // While some list is not empty
  while ( i < left.length || j < right.length ) {
    if ( i < left.length && ( j >= right.length || left[i] < right[j] ) ) {
      merged[k++] = left[i];
      ++i;
    } else {
      merged[k++] = right[j];
      ++j;
    }
  }
```